# Best approach: how to detect objects that have few features, but come in groups

Tags: opencv, image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network, yolo

My problem is very similar to detecting **birds flying in a flock**. The objects have few features, can be positioned with different angles in images. Objects can be positioned quite ocasionally in a group (not a regular grid), but they never intersect. I tried **YoloV3**: at start, as I had <30 training images, it worked quite good (**overfitted**, but at least it worked for training images). As I increased the number of training images, it stopped working, the network does not learn the data (**underfitting**). I think the main problem is, that the **objects have not enough features for CNN**, i.e. separate objects are too simple. I wanted to somehow use the fact that they always come in groups, i.e. somehow **consider neighbors**. There may be different number of them in groups, at least 3, but mostly > 10. They may look differently (like birds with different positions of wings), but the size of all objects in a group is about the same. I am a newbie in neural networks, so maybe someone with more experience could point me in the right direction.

I tried to use **template matching** from **OpenCV**: I must use many templates (>20), because objects may look quite differently (different positions of wings); and also multiscale matching is needed, that all takes much execution time. But more important is that, under different settings, template matching finds either too few objects, or too many false positives. So I think neural networks fit better for this task. Please correct me if I am wrong. I thought maybe it could make sense to mask "useful" regions with a pass through a **Mask-RCNN**, and then somehow separate the objects in these regions (because I have to mark them separately for the user). Could this work, or maybe there are some other ways I could try? Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I also have many other objects in images (not just sky and birds), for example like trees. And the leaves or groups of leaves give false positives. They may be of different color (green, orange, dark-green, black), so filtering them on color is hardly possible.

[image: flock of birds]
[image: trees]

Comment: What image resolutions do you use? Please post images where your recognition fails with YOLO.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you very much for your help! I did not try first versions of Yolo, I work with YoloV3. My images are 500x500 Pixels, and the objects I search are about 25-30 Pixels (25x25 ... 30x30). So this should not be a problem. And as I said, on a small training set the network worked quite good: almost all objects were found correctly, they all were good separated from each other. But as I added more training data (like birds with different positions of wings), the network stopped working.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I can't add my real images, because they are property of my customers (top secret!). Sorry :( But I edited my question (see "Edit" in the end, and a new image), that may help understanding the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from [**YOLO** introduction article](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/yolo.pdf):

> **2.4. Limitations of YOLO**
>
> YOLO imposes strong spatial constraints on bounding box predictions since each grid cell only predicts two boxes and can only have one class. This spatial constraint limits the number of nearby objects that our model can predict. **Our model struggles with small objects that appear ingroups, such as flocks of birds.**

Since YOLO version 1 the recognition of small and multiscale objects improved a lot but I didn't find any evidence that it got better in small **grouped** objects recognition (correct me if I am wrong please).

It will be problematic to recognise very small objects on large high-res images, as YOLOv3 will downscale them to 416x416 (or 320x320 if you use *YOLOv3 320*) resolution. You can feed YOLOv3 regions of an image if it is too big. Or you can find some existing solutions for such cases.

In [this article](https://nae-lab.org/%7Erei/publication/takeki-icip2016.pdf) guys combined a CNN-based detector with a fully convolutional network and a superpixel-based semantic segmentation by using support vector machines to achieve high performance in detecting small objects in large images. They claim to achieve high detection precision.

---

But often you can utilize much easier approaches that involve only a little bit of algorithmical image processing, if the relative difference between object you want ot detect and its environment is obvious and simple to calculate.

You can try to detect a flock by high color contrast between birds and sky. Usually birds appear much darker on sky background. You may find [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) and this [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) OpenCV docs about image thresholding helpful for that.

```
int main(){
    Mat src = imread("1.jpg");
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat thresholded;
    threshold(gray, thresholded, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    imwrite("2.jpg", thresholded);
    return 0;
}
```

I got this:

[image: My]

Now you can extract white bird blobs with [`findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) or [`SimpleBlobDetector`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html) (and match them against templates or do additional recognition/classification if that is required).

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your help! I have already tried thresholding, but I did not know about SimpleBlobDetector. I will try your ideas, but unfortunatelly I can't always rely only on a contrast between background and objects. On my real data in many cases the contrast is not that good like in my example image with birds and sky. Although, in combination with other methods, thresholding can help me, you are right. The article about CNNs is also new for me, thanks!